# asyncio.gather not waiting long enough for all tasks to complete

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-asyncio

I'm writing a code to get some links from a list of input urls using asyncio, aiohttp and BeautifulSoup.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
def async_get_jpg_links(links):
    def extractLinks(ep_num, html):
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml', 
            parse_only = bs4.SoupStrainer('article'))
        main = soup.findChildren('img')
        return ep_num, [img_link.get('data-src') for img_link in main]

    async def get_htmllinks(session, ep_num, ep_link):
        async with session.get(ep_link) as response:
            html_txt = await response.text()
        return extractLinks(ep_num, html_txt)

    async def get_jpg_links(ep_links):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = [get_htmllinks(session, num, link) 
                    for num, link in enumerate(ep_links, 1)]
            return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(get_jpg_links(links))
```

I then later call `jpgs_links = dict(async_get_jpg_links(hrefs))`, where hrefs is a bunch of links (~170 links).

`jpgs_links` should be a dictionary with numerical keys and a bunch of lists as values. Some of the values come back as empty lists (which should instead be filled with data). When I cut down the numbers of links in `hrefs`, more of the lists come back full.

For the photo below, I reran the same code with a minute between, and as you can see, I get different lists that come back empty and different ones that come back full.

Could it be that asyncio.gather is not waiting for all the tasks to finish?

How can I get asyncio to get me to return no empty lists, while keeping the number of links in `hrefs` high?

[image: result of the code]

Comment: Are you sure the URLs are provided in the same order each time? How is `hrefs` populated?

Comment: Have you tried adding prints to check which lists come out empty, and what is the `text` in that case. Perhaps you are getting incomplete HTML or HTML that BeautifulSoup can't deal with for some reason. It is highly unlikely that `gather` is not waiting for all the tasks to finish, and if it did, you wouldn't get an empty list out of it, you'd get `None` or an exception. Barring an asyncio bug, the only reason for `gather` not to wait for all tasks is if a task raises an exception, but then that exception would be propagated through `get_jpg_links` to the `run_until_complete` invocation.

Comment: I've added `if not main: print (f'{ep_num} has empty main.')` to the function `extractLinks` and this prints different ep_num every time I run it. So then, I think it's it soup.find_all('img') that returns the empty list. Would you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out that some of the urls I sent in threw up the error:

```
raise ClientResponseError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 504, message='Gateway Time-out',...
```

So I changed

```
async def get_htmllinks(session, ep_num, ep_link):
        async with session.get(ep_link) as response:
            html_txt = await response.text()
        return extractLinks(ep_num, html_txt)
```

to

```
async def get_htmllinks(session, ep_num, ep_link):
    html_txt = None
    while not html_txt:
        try:
            async with session.get(ep_link) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                html_txt = await response.text()
        except aiohttp.ClientResponseError:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return extractLinks(ep_num, html_txt)
```

What this does is that it retries the connection after sleeping for a second (the `await asyncio.sleep(1)` does that).

Nothing to do with asyncio or BeautifulSoup, apparently.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the dict, though. The exception should have been propagated and raised from `run_until_complete`.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to mention that the error was raised once I added the line `response.raise_for_status()` to the code. That's why the dict was able to be created before.

Comment: That makes sense - so the html you obtained before `raise_for_status` was probably just an error template, in which BeautifulSoup would find nothing and you'd end up with an empty list.